# PDO Insert error on execute

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I can't find my mistake, I'm getting Execute fail error

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=xxxxxx', 'yyyyyy', 'zzzzzz', array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")) or die ("fail");;
$query = "INSERT INTO multiTicker (mtgox,btcstamp,btce,btcchina,myDateTime) VALUES (:mtgox,:btcstamp,:btce,:btcchina,:myDateTime)";
$st = $db->prepare($query) or die ("Query fail");
$st->execute(array(':mtgox' => $mtgox,
               ':btcstamp' => $btcstamp,
               ':btce' => $btce,
               ':btcchina' => $btcchina,
               ':myDateTime' => $myDateTime)) or die ("Execute fail");
```

Comment: @Fred-ii- Two semi-colons isn't going to break anything. Also, when the PDO constructor fails, it throws a `PDOException` so that `or die` will never run anyway.

Comment: Thanks Phil, I wasn't entirely sure about that. @Phil

Comment: Please don't ask a question on StackOverflow and say *"I'm getting Execute fail error"* without actually providing the **error message**.

Comment: My apologies I wasn't receiving any error message I'll remember to find out and include it next time. Phil's error mode printed the error which allowed me to find my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your DSN is incorrect (you have a space in it). Try this PDO constructor and **stop using `or die()`**!

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxxxxx;charset=utf8', 'yyyyyy', 'zzzzzz', array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

$query = "INSERT INTO multiTicker (mtgox,btcstamp,btce,btcchina,myDateTime) VALUES (:mtgox,:btcstamp,:btce,:btcchina,:myDateTime)";
$st = $db->prepare($query);
$st->execute(array(
    ':mtgox' => $mtgox,
    ':btcstamp' => $btcstamp,
    ':btce' => $btce,
    ':btcchina' => $btcchina,
    ':myDateTime' => $myDateTime
));
```

You don't have to set the default fetch mode to `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` but I find it's handy.

Comment: This allowed me to find my error message which were null values