# What's wrong with this MySQL query? (using PDO)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This is my first time trying to use Named Placeholders so I'm sure I have a syntax error somewhere... I just don't see it. I am following the directions I found [here](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers#Named_Placeholders). I am expecting the array, `$authResults`, to contain the row that has $user's information if the password matches $pass.

If my query is simply `SELECT * FROM user` it works. Obviously, that won't work in a production environment. :-)

Here's what I have so far:

```
$user= "Test";
$pass= "ba6c064dfdb1b7b4938bf82585a8332c89270303b6d75007f0b25feffe33b90bd34d3732acf4be708c85708c39ff6c28b87235663238b8fbfe2c4439258cc883";

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', 'admin', 'pass');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

//query database to see if username/password match up
$authQuery = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username=:usr AND password=:pwd");  // search for username and password
$authQuery->bindValue(':usr', $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$authQuery->bindValue(':pwd', $pass, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$authQuery->execute();
$authResults = $authQuery->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


echo "<br><br>authResults:<pre>";
print_r($authResults);
echo "</pre>";
```

Thoughts?

Here's the output that's echoed at the end of my file:

```
authResults:
Array
(
)
```

There are no error messages. Is there a character limit for PHP variables or for MySQL queries?

Comment: What errors do you get? What is not working as expected? Have you considered actually trying to verify that prepared statement, query execution ,etc . give expected results? As it stands, your code doesn't show any attempt to verify you are getting the results you expect before continuing execution.

Comment: `print_r()` is not what you want. Use a while loop.

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump($authQuery->errorInfo());` for seeing the error? Are you sure your fields are called `username` and `password`?

Comment: @PHPglue `print_r` will show an array just fine

Comment: I added info about error messages (or lack thereof). I'm not sure what else you're asking me to do. I've never used a prepared statement so how do I verify if it gives the expected results? It's not giving the expected results. Will try using var_dump right now.

Comment: You should try the `var_dump()` after the execute, forgot to say

Comment: Another possibility is that the query is working, but there is simply no row that matched the values you are searching for. I would suggest testing it by searching only for the username, not the password. Then print the password it finds (of course, only in your development, not on your production site) and see if that matches the hash you expect it to be.

Comment: var_dump() gives this: `array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "00000" [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL }`

Comment: It seems that there's no mysql error then... check out @BillKarwin 's comment. Otherwise, check that `$user` and `$pass` are properly set.

Comment: Your code looks completely fine and I'd say @BillKarwin has hit the nail on the head. Just out of curiosity, how have you instantiated your PDO instance and what attributes have you set? I recommend [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20234175/pdo-insert-error-on-execute/20234306#20234306)

Comment: I tried the query without the password and it finds the user. The password it finds matches the password I'm trying to pass into the query. I've echoed the password right before the query, just to make sure and, yes, it matches up perfectly.

Comment: Does the password look exactly like that in the database? It has too. That is a bad practice to have the password on your page like that in the real world. In MySQL, use `AES_ENCRYPT()` and `AES_DECRYPT()` with a `blob`.

Comment: @Phil I've done this.... `$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', 'admin', 'pass');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` - taking a look at your suggestion now

Comment: Yes the password is the same in the database as the one printed before the query and as the one returned by the query.

Comment: @KennyJohnson Looks good though you can set attributes via the fourth constructor argument. I'd use `strcmp` or some other string comparison mechanism to check the password string equality. It's easy to miss a single character in strings that long

Comment: Please show your database structure.

Comment: @PHPglue what's the best way to do that? The table I'm working with is called `users`. There are several columns but the two I'm working with are `username` and `password`.  Is the rest of the database relevant?

Comment: Is there a character limit for PHP variables or for MySQL queries? I tried this with another column in the database named `user_id` and it returned the result. Only when I try to do it with the password that it won't work. The password is a hash of what the user types in (pass, in this case) so they aren't actually typing all of those characters.

Comment: Perhaps there is some whitespace in the password field that is not present in the value you are passing. If you query "select LENGTH(user.password);" do you get the expected result (128)?

Comment: @AllInOne, good suggestion, I have frequently seen hashing functions have problems if a newline creeps in, either before or after the hashing is applied.

Comment: Showing table structure can be done with `SHOW CREATE TABLE user` or `DESCRIBE user`. Feel free to show only the columns for username and pass. I would expect pass to be CHAR(128). See [MySQL: what data type to use for hashed password field and what length?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247304/mysql-what-data-type-to-use-for-hashed-password-field-and-what-length/247627#247627)

Comment: `CREATE TABLE usrpwdkeys(
  usr TINYBLOB NOT NULL,
  pwd TINYBLOB NOT NULL
)ENGINE = INNODB;
INSERT urspwdkeys VALUES ('C@x9H7^nb*', 'a_MF8B2&bx');`

Answer (score 1):

That simply means that your query hasn't matched anything. Be careful on how your user/pass are stored in your table.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question you asked about how would you go about this:

```
// simple database structure
CREATE TABLE usrpwdkeys(
  usr TINYBLOB NOT NULL,
  pwd TINYBLOB NOT NULL
)ENGINE=INNODB;
INSERT usrpwdkeys VALUES ('C@x9H7^nb*','a_MF8B2&bx');
CREATE TABLE usrpwd(
  pk BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  usr BLOB NOT NULL,
  pwd BLOB NOT NULL
)ENGINE=INNODB;

// put your database connection on a secure page - restricted/connect.php
<?php
function db(){
  return new mysqli('host', 'username', 'password', 'database');
}

// putting the results into the database - newuser.php
<?php
$error = '';
if(isset($_POST['sub']) && !empty($_POST['user']) && !empty($_POST['pass'])){
  include_once 'restricted/connect.php'; $db = db();
  if($db->connect_error)die('connection failed');
  $upk = $db->query('SELECT * FROM usrpwdkeys'); $kys = $upk->fetch_row();
  $upk->free(); $usr = $db->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['user']));
  $pwd = sha1(md5($usr).$db->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['pass'])).'a5cJ');
  $uxs = $db->query("SELECT pk FROM usrpwd WHERE usr=AES_ENCRYPT('$usr','$upk[0]')");
  if($uxs->num_rows > 0){
    $error = 'Username in Use'; // error on password shows too much
  }
  elseif($db->query("INSERT usrpwd (usr,pwd) VALUES (AES_ENCRYPT('$usr','$upk[0]'), AES_ENCRYPT('$pwd','$upk[1]'))")){
    header('LOCATION:wherever.php'); // goes to other page
  }
  else{
    die('problem');
  }
  $uxs->free(); $db->close();
}
// Should be much more complex than just this - HTML structure should be below

// simple login - login.php
session_start(); $error = '';
if(isset($_POST['sub']) && !empty($_POST['user']) && !empty($_POST['pass'])){
  include_once 'restricted/connect.php'; $db = db();
  if($db->connect_error)die('connection failed');
  $upk = $db->query('SELECT * FROM usrpwdkeys'); $kys = $upk->fetch_row();
  $upk->free(); $usr = $db->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['user']));
  $pwd = sha1(md5($usr).$db->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['pass'])).'a5cJ');
  $log = $db->query("SELECT pk FROM usrpwd WHERE usr=AES_ENCRYPT('$usr','$upk[0]') && pwd=AES_ENCRYPT('$pwd','$upk[1]')");
  if($log->num_rows > 0){
    $_SESSION['log'] = 'Ao@8a!45'; $_SESSION['usr'] = $usr;
    header('LOCATION:wherever.php'); // goes to other page that should retest against database
  }
  else{
    $error = 'Invalid Password and/or Username';
  }
  $log->free(); $db->close();
}
// once again should be way more complex
```

Naturally, you would probably want to use regular expressions for the username and password. The library [PHPglue](https://phpglue.com) can take care of most, if not all of your Stick Form Regular Expression Error Handling.

Comment: Please don't use reversible encryption to store passwords. Use a non-reversible hash.

Comment: Added `sha1()` plus `AES_ENCYPT()`. I would use other salts as well.